# Query MS Access 2010 (accdb) with Matlab

Tags: matlab, ms-access

I would like to make a query in MS Access 2010 (.accdb file) with matlab.
I would like to send a query (for ex: "SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE") and be able to read the result.

If it is not possible with a .accdb file I will use .mdb.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Database Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/database/).